# ParaView: Must Data Be Loaded Into One Node?

Tags: mesh, paraview

I have a very large data set: 512x512x512 cells. Loading the mesh into the memory takes over 120GB and the memory on a single node is a problem for me. I am wandering if paraview can load the data in memory on multiple nodes so that there is more memory in total?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, yes. ParaView can be run in parallel (http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/Users_Guide_Client-Server_Visualization) to distribute the data across nodes.

What kind of file format this is? Based on  the file-format, the reader could either read in partitioned data on processes or will read on single node and then one will have to redistribute using filters.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into the client-server mode. My data is generated from OpenFOAM and it is available on a single node. Can you provide more information on using filters.